# Como consigo puxar dados de uma tabela que contém várias linhas e com uma coluna que contém os mesmos "ID's"?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, tabela-banco-de-dados

```sql
SELECT 
    magento.sales_order.entity_id AS 'ID',
    magento.sales_order.increment_id AS 'PEDIDO',
    magento.sales_order_grid.payment_method AS 'MÉTODO DE PAGAMENTO',
    magento.sales_order_status_history.comment AS 'COMENTARIOS',
    magento.sales_order_status_history.entity_id AS 'ID STATUS',
    magento.sales_order.created_at AS "CRIACAO",
    magento.sales_order.status AS "STATUS"
FROM
    magento.sales_order
    JOIN magento.sales_order_status_history ON     magento.sales_order_status_history.entity_id = magento.sales_order.entity_id
    JOIN magento.sales_order_grid ON magento.sales_order.increment_id = magento.sales_order_grid.increment_id
WHERE
    magento.sales_order.entity_id = 64671
ORDER BY magento.sales_order.increment_id DESC
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: olá, tente por um titulo mais resumido, e adicione os detalhes no texto da pergunta. Ainda não ficou bem claro o que pretende, explique melhor

Comment: Pouco claro mas tente GROUP_CONCAT ... https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/

Answer (score -3):

WHERE
magento.sales_order.entity_id = magento.sales_order.increment_id

reanalisando talvez o seu where não está sendo direcionado ao local correto, ele talvez devesse direcionar aos ids, já que algumas das informações coincidem com mesmo id